# Replace custom brackets with specific content

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to replace **{all-content}^{^}** into **\hat{all-content}**. And the string and expected output should be like ...

```
|---------------------|-------------------|-------------------|
|    String Input     |  Expected Result  |     What I get    |
|---------------------|-------------------|-------------------|
|        {A}^{^}      |     \hat{A}       |       \hat{A}     |
|---------------------|-------------------|-------------------|
|   {{A}_{22}}^{^}    |  \hat{{A}_{22}}   |   \hat{{A}_{22}}  |
|---------------------|-------------------|-------------------|
| {A}_{X-1} {B+2}^{^} |{A}_{X-1} \hat{B+2}|\hat{A}_{X-1} {B+2}|
|---------------------|-------------------|-------------------|
|   {A+{B}^{^}}^{^}   | \hat{A+\hat{B}}   | \hat{A+{B}}^{^}   |
|---------------------|-------------------|-------------------|
```

Here is the regex ..

```
str = str.replace(/\{(.*?)\}\^\{\^\}/g, "\\hat{$1}")
```

```js
str = '{A}^{^} this is sample content {{A}_{22}}^{^} with more complex structure {A}_{X-1} {B+2}^{^} another content with multi level content {A+{B}^{^}}^{^}';
str = str.replace(/\{(.*?)\}\^\{\^\}/g, "\\hat{$1}");
console.log(str)
```

Update:
{...} --> could be any character, special character or unicode symbols. May also contains more than one level of nested curly braces.

So is it possible in regex ? if not, any other alternatives ..

Comment: Say, in **words**, what the rule for the contents of the opening `{...}` is.

Comment: {...} will be in [tex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TeX) format ...in general any character including special characters and unicode symbols

Comment: Because your fourth example requires recursion through nested structures, JavaScript's regular expressions are not able to do this on their own. You'll need more complicated parsing.

Comment: (Use "edit" to improve/clarify the question, rather than comments.)

Comment: Unless there can be more than 1 nested level of curly braces, this can be done with a regex. If there can be arbitrary number of nested levels, it is not possible with a regex. See [this demo](https://jsfiddle.net/4Lgj5r25/).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: True. I made an assumption there, that seeing one level of nesting, there could be more than one.

Comment: Anyway, a regex is a bad idea here. Writing a parsing function or using an existing library is a preferred way.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, not perfect because it assumes each match contains the same number of `^{^}` and `{` but should work in most cases :

```js
let re = /{.*?}[^\s]+/g;
let text = "{A}^{^} this is sample content {{A}_{22}}^{^} with more complex structure {A}_{X-1} {B+2}^{^} another content with multi level content {A+{B}^{^}}^{^}";

text.match(re).map(m => {  
  let replacement = m;
  
  replacement = replacement.replace(/\^{\^}/g, "");
  replacement = replacement.replace(/{/g, "\\hat{");
  
  text = text.replace(m, replacement);
});

console.log(text);
```

Comment: My first attempt was not working properly, I deleted it, here is another one.

Answer (score -1):

If I understand your problem correctly, it's that the lazy quantifier isn't lazy in the right direction.

in the string `{A}_{X-1} {B+2}^{^}` you want to catch {A}_{X-1} **{B+2}^{^}** but it sees the beginning brackets and takes **{A}_{X-1} {B+2}^{^}**.

One solution is to disallow `{` in the string, like this:

```
\{([^\{]*?)\}\^\{\^\}
```

or, if you want to disallow any white space characters it would also work.